# show post view in post grid of visual composer

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I use of Visual composer and Betheme wordpress theme.
I want show post view in post grid, but grid builder of visual composer haven't and i don't to use of plugin for this.
what do i do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcode which display post in grid format and place that shortcode in any page where you want to display post in grid format.